# How does MS Office know I had previous version installed?

Tags: microsoft-office

I tried to install MS Office 2010 Pro Plus (Technical Preview). 
It did not go through. Don't know why - said some error during installation. Could be bad image or something.

So I downloaded another one (same - MS Office 2010 Pro Plus, but regular one, not Technical Preview). And during installation it gave an error "Microsoft Office does not support upgrade from prerelease version". And it didn't install.

So I googled that error.
Tried to remove every file called "Office" I could find on PC. Scanned Registry for "msoffice" and removed one thing. Not sure what it did. But installer still didn't work.

Now only thing I can think of is reinstall Windows entirely. But don't wanna do it.
Mb. someone could help?

Comment: Is there a way to trace what it does? In Linux I could just run it in console and read the log. But it's binary.

Comment: Yes, you can trace HDD, Registry, Processes in real-time using a tool called **ProcessMonitor** (its originally from SysInternals now owned by Microsoft). It will yield too much information for you to diagnose the root cause preventing the installation - you're better off checking the [Applicability rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843971/how-to-programmatically-check-the-applicability-rules-of-a-windows-update/29887586#29887586). The easiest is following the advice in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **MSICUU2 tool** to remove remnants of software. Get a copy of it [here](http://JeremyThompson.net/Rocks/msicuu2.exe).

Its the original tool that the "Fix It" *supposedly* replaces, except it actually works!

Select the old version of Office and click remove:
[image]

Comment: Doesn't start. Gives VBScript error.

Comment: Run the Microsoft Msicuu2 exe as an admin to install

Answer (score -1):

1. Try this [Fix it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971179), which has an automatic way of uninstalling a broken office 2003-2010 install.
2. Try the [Program Install and Uninstall troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall).